# Fetch top 5 customers from Mysql table

Tags: mysql

i have a table 'tbl_orders', that table contains the folllowing

```
order_id | customer_id | grand_total
```

now i need to fetch out the TOP 5 customer which have more orders with me

i try the query below,

```
"SELECT customer_id , count(customer_id) as total_orders FROM `tbl_order` group by customer_id"
```

But this query only give me all customer_id & total_orders of each customer & i want to fetch TOP 5 customer, i.e having more orders with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to DonCallisto's answer, you might want to also sort by the highest number of orders. Otherwise you won't get the top 5.

```
SELECT customer_id , count(order_id) as total_orders 
FROM `tbl_order` 
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY total_orders DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Notice I also changed the count column from customer_id to order_id. This doesn't make any difference functionally, but it makes more sense to someone reading your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT customer_id , count(customer_id) as total_orders 
FROM `tbl_order` GROUP BY customer_id ORDER BY total_orders DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: aha thanks its working, but u have error in your syntax

ORDER BY total_orders should be after DESC group by customer_id but u put it before :)

Comment: @Arif : yes, I thought i made it as it is now.

Comment: ya now it ok, Thanks a million for helping me